# Await not waiting in async function

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

welcome to my first SO question. I am trying to make a call to Spotify's API from my Express backend, and I am unable to get the data returned properly. The API request is not the problem - the correct information gets returned, I just can't seem to retrieve that info.

Here is the route which calls the `getOldTracks` function that contains the API call.

```
router.post("/remix", async (req, res) => {
  // Fetch song information
  const oldTracks = await getOldTracks(req.body.playlistId, req.user.username).then((data) => {
    console.log('returned to original call',data);
    return data;
  }).catch((err) => {console.log('this is an error',err)});

});
```

I originally tried to directly return the `setUpSpotifyApi` function, but it would just return a pending promise that would just resolve into undefined. I am trying it with `trackList` to try to see the order of what gets called.

```
const getOldTracks = async (playlistId, userName) => {
  let trackList = null;
  await setUpSpotifyApi(userName)
    .then((spotifyApi) => {
      spotifyApi.getPlaylist(playlistId).then(
        (data) => {
          console.log('in spotify api call',data.body.tracks.items)
          trackList = data.body.tracks.items;
         // return data.body.tracks.items;
        },
        (err) => {
          console.log("Error grabbing playlist", err);
        }
      );
    })
    .catch((error) => {
      console.log(error);
    });
  console.log('after await',trackList);
  return trackList
};
```

Here is what the console shows. This is for a playlist with no tracks, so the empty array is correct

```
after await null
returned to original call null
in spotify api call []
```

I really do not understand why `getOldTracks` returns the null `trackList`. Why does it keep executing after I specify to await the spotify call? I am not too experienced with asynchronous JS, but I have never had problems like this. I was unable to solve this with promises too, so I am at a loss for why it is executing in incorrect order.

Comment: This is the kind of trouble you get into when you mix `await` and `.then()`.   Change all `.then()` to use `await` and change all `.catch()` to use `try/catch` and your problem will disappear.  You aren't chaining your inner promise to the outer one by returning it - therefore the outer promise has no idea when the inner one is done and thus can't wait for it.  But, you don't have to worry about that if you consistently use `await` instead of mixing the two programming styles.

Comment: @jfriend00 Yeah I see what you mean. Originally I was trying to do all `.then()`, but when I couldn't get it working I just started throwing the async/awaits stuff at it. I'll need to learn this stuff better

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to `await` the inner promise, right now you return before `spotifyApi.getPlaylist` has completed

```
const spotifyApi = await setUpSpotifyApi(userName);
await spotifyApi.getPlaylist(playlistId).then(
    (data) => {
      console.log('in spotify api call',data.body.tracks.items)
      trackList = data.body.tracks.items;
     // return data.body.tracks.items;
    },
    (err) => {
      console.log("Error grabbing playlist", err);
    }
  );
})
```